# How to pause the starting of the activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my game there is an animation at the end before levelcomplete activity starts so to make animation seen properly I am using Handler (Runnable) in which I am doing `startActivity(this,Levlecomplete.class)`

There is an pause buton in my game which starts PauseActivity. Now issue i am facing is when that end animation is started and if pause button is pressed in that delay time of runnable my game opens the pause activity and just after the runnable task delay is ended it opens the level complete activity on that.

I do not know how to pause the LevelCompleteactivity to start. I want if pause button is pressed in between the last animation then I want runnable to open levelcomplete activity only after the pause activity is finish.

How to pause the activity from starting ?

How to achieve that any one please?

Answer (score 0):

I think may be the pause should never start when a level of your game come to an end, it's strange to pause at that time.